# How to calculate the sum of the elements of an array of integers using P processors

Tags: c, linux

I have to add the elements of an array of integers using P processors. Below it's the code i've written so far. I have defined an array and a number of 4 processors to can make some tests.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#define P 17
#define SIZE 153

static pid_t id[P];
static int elementsList[] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,
            1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,
            1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,
            1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,
            1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,
            1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,
            1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,
            1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,
            1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17
            };

void getSubvectorSum(int elemList[], int start, int step, int size,int wPipe){
int sum = 0;
int i;
for(i = start; i < size; i += step){
    sum += elemList[i];
}
write(wPipe,&sum,sizeof sum);
}

int main(){
int fd[2];
int total = 0;
int result;
int nbytes;
int i;
pipe(fd);
for(i = 0; i < P; i++){
    id[i] = fork();
    if(id[i] == 0){
                    close(fd[0]);
        getSubvectorSum(elementsList,i,P,SIZE,fd[1]);
        exit(0);
    }
}
for(i = 0; i < P; i++){
    wait(NULL);
}
close(fd[1];
for(i = 0; i < P; i++){
    nbytes = read(fd[0],&result,sizeof result);
    if(nbytes > 0){
        printf("Something on the pipe.\n");
        total += result;

    } else {
        printf("Nothing on the pipe.\n");
    }
}   
for(i = 0; i < P; i++){
    kill(id[i],SIGKILL);
}
printf("total result: %d\n",total);
return 0;

}
```

Am I doing things right?

Comment: What happens when you run it? Does it produce the correct result?

Comment: I have made tests on the defined array and the result was correct.I don't know what happens in other circumstances, for example if the array has a large number of elements or the number of processes is biger

Comment: Well, that's strong evidence that your program is fine. Apart from a missing parenthesis (which I assume is a copy-and-paste error) I can't see anything wrong with the code. Perhaps add some error checking to the code? Also, `kill()` seems unnecessary.

Comment: As to not knowing what happens in other cases, just test those other cases and you'll know.

Comment: The ultimate tests for this are performance and scalability.  If you scale up to say, 1 million elements (you'll have to allocate your array dynamically), does it still work?  If you vary P, the number of processes, does that affect performance in ways you would expect?  (run your program under `time`)

Comment: Your program will create P additional processes. There's no guarantee that they will run on different processors.

Comment: Why do you `kill` the child processes? They call exit so they should die without the need for `kill`.

Comment: I am a beginner and as far as i have read that i have avoid zombies. I will improve the code and make some tests on exit, to make sure that every process has exited successfully.

Comment: I have made tests on this size of the array and with 17 processes and after a few seconds the server connection suspends. That means that i am doing something wrong. What about the pipe size?

Comment: Leaving aside the mechanics (which many comments address), you might want to try splitting the array so that each process gets a contiguous part, instead of having all the processes leapfrog each other. Contiguous access is more cache-friendly, and may allow vectorization if your compiler can optimize for that.

Comment: The child should close the input end of the pipe. Add a `close(fd[0])` before calling `getSubvectorSum`

Comment: Zombies are created when you don't 'reap' the children. If your parent process creates a child process but doesn't read the exit code of the child process, you have a zombie. You can `wait` for the child's exit code but when the parent dies, its zombies will disappear. Calling `kill` will not reap the child process.

Comment: What do you think that makes my server connection to suspend?

Comment: I don't have a Unix machine to test on but when you fork, each handle gets duplicated so you need to close your half of the pipe. You may also try to create a separate pipe per process but you should still close the end of the pipe you don't use.

Comment: You may want to change `SIZE` to `#define SIZE (sizeof(elementList)/sizeof(elementList[0]))`. This way you won't have to recalculate it every time you change the size of `elementList`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You program might deadlock with large number of processes: once the pipe buffer is full, children will block on `write()` while the parent will `wait()`. Drain the pipe in the parent without waiting for the child processes to complete.

Your program might read less bytes than written by children.

Check error conditions of system calls. It might make it easier to uncover bugs.

I'm not sure but you might need to retry `wait()` call on `EINTR` error; otherwise you'll create zombies.

You shouldn't need to `kill`.

Look at [`parallel-sum-fork.c` and `parallel-sum-openmp.c`](https://gist.github.com/7437668) for comparison.